# Android JetCreator deepcopy error

Tags: android, python

I’m trying to use the JetCreator python application that comes with the Android SDK to create sound files for Android.  I get an error trying to play a midi segment using the provided JetCreator demo that come with the Android SDK android-sdk-r12-windows.zip.  It tried it with Windows XP and Windows 7. First I installed python 2.7 and wxPython2.8-win32->unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.exe and am able to run the hello world wx program. Next I  run JetCreator.py, the gui starts, I select some mdi segments to play (and hit the play button), and I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method JetCreator.PlaySegs of <_
_main__.JetCreator; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxFrame *' at 0x1ca9378> >>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\_tools\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\Jet\JetCreator\JetCreator.py
", line 1230, in PlaySegs
jet_file = CreateTempJetFile(self.jet_file)
File "C:\_tools\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\Jet\JetCreator\JetUtils.py",
line 759, in CreateTempJetFile
jet_file = copy.deepcopy(org_jet_file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 344, in _reconstruct
state = deepcopy(state, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 298, in _deepcopy_inst
state = deepcopy(state, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
y = copier(memo)
TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object
```

I don't want to fix JetCreator.py necessarily, but is there something wrong with my configuration perhaps?

Thanks, 
Paul

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this, but when I saw that you were having the same error with the same version of Python and WXPython as I was using I figured it must have something to do with the fact that the version the program was built with is no longer supported as it's from 2008. It took me a bit of digging but I eventually found the two original programs and now everything works perfectly.

Python 2.5.4
http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/

WXPython 2.8.7.1
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.7.1/wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.7.1-py25.exe/download

I don't know why google hasn't updated the program to be compatible with currently supported versions of these programs, but for now this is what worked for me!